# Do resources in a URL path have their own IP address?

Tags: http, url

So, a DNS server recognizes https://www.google.com as 173.194.34.5

What does, say, https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png look like to a server? Or are URL strings machine readable?

Answer (score 3):

Good question!

When you access a url, first a DNS lookup will be done on the host part (`www.google.com`), after that the browser will look at the protocol and connect using that (`https` in this case).

After connecting, the browser will tell the server:

"Hi! I'm trying to connect to `www.google.com` and I would like the resource `/images/srpr/logo11w.png`). This looks like this on the protocol:

```
GET /images/srpr/logo11w.png HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google.com
```

The `Host` part is a HTTP header. There are usually more headers.

So the short answer is:

The server will get access to both the hostname, and the full path the browser tried to access.

Comment: so `/images/srpr/logo11w.png` is machine readable then? Like, a set of instructions for retrieving data? I think my question is a bit more computer science-y than I realized, I'm wondering what the data looks like.

Comment: Yes the server receives it as a string. The data looks _exactly_ like the HTTP request I posted. That's what the client sends, and the server receives.

Comment: The HTTP request is really the 'instruction' you talk about.

Answer (score 2):

> https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png

consists of several parts

- protocol (https)
- address of the server (www.google.com, that gets translated to IP)
- path to the resource (/images/srpr/logo11w.png, in this example it seems like it would be an image in a directory `srpr`, which is in a directory `images` in the root of the website)

The server processes path to the resource the user requested (via GET method) based on various rules and returns a response.